# Incompatible OSAL interfaces in Rhapsody

Tags: freertos, rhapsody

I'm trying to create OSAL (Operating System Abstraction Layer) adapter for FreeRTOS but confused with the provided interfaces.

For example, init function of RiCOSTask is defined as follows in the docs :

```
RiCBoolean RiCOSTask_init (RiCOSTask *const me,
    RiCOSTaskEndCallBack tfunc, void *param,
    const char *name, const long stackSize);
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.1.3/com.ibm.rhp.reference.doc/topics/rhp_r_fw_init_ricostask.html

But RiCTaskEM calls this function like below :

```
RiCBoolean RiCTaskEM_init(RiCBoolean wrapTask,RiCThread * const 
itsThread,RiCBoolean isThread,const RiCOSTaskEntryCallBack cbkFunc,const 
RhpAddress cbkParam,RhpPositive initStaticPeriod)
{
        ..........

        (RhpVoid) RiCOSTask_init(&(itsThread->osTask), cbkFunc, cbkParam, initStaticPeriod);

        ...........
}
```

I guess something is wrong with my configuration. I'm using SMXF with Rhapsody 8.1.3.

Another issue is, init function of my test class calls the RiCTaskEM_init method like below :

```
void smxfTestClass_Init(smxfTestClass* const me, RiCTaskEM * p_task) {
    RiCTaskEM_init(&(me->ric_task), RiCFALSE, &(me->ric_thread), RiCTRUE,
        (RiCOSTaskEntryCallBack)smxfTestClass_doExecute, me, 0U);
    .......
}
```

But if I set a property of my class, eg. ActiveThreadName, the call to RiCTaskEM_Init function is changed like this :

```
void smxfTestClass_Init(smxfTestClass* const me, RiCTaskEM * p_task) {
    RiCTaskEM_Init(&(me->ric_task), "Test", RiCOSDefaultThreadPriority,
        RiCOSDefaultStackSize, RiCOSDefaultMessageQueueSize, RiCFALSE, NULL);
    ......
}
```

And the compilation fails because the prototype of RiCTaskEM_Init is not compatible with the above call. It is defined like this :

```
RiCBoolean RiCTaskEM_init(RiCBoolean wrapTask,RiCThread * const
    itsThread,RiCBoolean isThread,const RiCOSTaskEntryCallBack cbkFunc,const
    RhpAddress cbkParam,RhpPositive initStaticPeriod)
```

- What is happening ? Do I have a mismatch between the Rhapsody version and the SMXF model I am using ?
- Why RiCTaskEM_init method is called in a different way if I set a property of my class ? The second version seems to be the correct one but provided RiCTaskEM_init method is not compatible with that.
- Do I have to modify functions of RiCTaskEM somehow ? I guess no because it belongs to framework, not the adaptor and OSAL adaptor guide doesn't mention anything about it. But the current implementation simply does not fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is written for the OXF, not for the SMXF Framework. As far as I know there is no real documentation for adapting an SMXF but.. the SMXF is there as a model (Check your /LangC/smxf directory)
this should make it easier to  create an adapter.
Do you really need the SMXF or would an OXF suffice (or even another Framework like RXF?

Walter

Comment: Hi Walter, you're right. It took time to notice that it belongs to a different framework. We've successfuly implemented it by imitating the QNX adapter.